# Specifying columns in gridview just adds more columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview where I only want certain columns from the query to show (1 is used for sorting). Below I tried to define the columns but for some reason its rendering the columns and then all of the columns in the query afterwords.

```
<asp:GridView ID="taskGridView" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Person" HeaderText="Person" SortExpression="Person" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Effort" HeaderText="Effort" SortExpression="Effort" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Task" HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="Task" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalEstimateHours" HeaderText="OriginalEstimateHours" SortExpression="OriginalEstimateHours" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total" />
             </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
        </center>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

How do I only show desired columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridView` control has a property `AutoGenerateColumns`, that specifies whether the control should generate columns based on the data source that was given to it. Default value of this property is **true** ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), which means that default behavior is to generate all columns and then append markup-defined ones.

To disable this behavior simply set this property to **false**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="taskGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ...
```